# Question Regarding some Haverbeke "Eloquent JavaScript" Constructor Code

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, instantiation, arrow-functions

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding a few lines of code from page 108 of Marijn Haverbeke's "Eloquent JavaScript" book.

Namely, in the example below, I don't understand what "**element = (x, y) => undefined**" in the constructor parameter list is doing, when the Matrix object is instantiated with "**let matrix = new Matrix(3, 3, (x, y) => `value ${x}, ${y}`);**"

Can some step-by-step it for me?  It seems like we are passing a function to the constructor, but I don't get why the constructor parameter list is setup the way it is with another arrow function.

```
var Matrix = class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  }

  get(x, y) {
    return this.content[y * this.width + x];
  }
  set(x, y, value) {
    this.content[y * this.width + x] = value;
  }
}

var MatrixIterator = class MatrixIterator {
  constructor(matrix) {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.matrix = matrix;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.y == this.matrix.height) return {done: true};

    let value = {x: this.x,
                 y: this.y,
                 value: this.matrix.get(this.x, this.y)};
    this.x++;
    if (this.x == this.matrix.width) {
      this.x = 0;
      this.y++;
    }
    return {value, done: false};
  }
}

Matrix.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
  return new MatrixIterator(this);
};

let matrix = new Matrix(3, 3, (x, y) => `value ${x}, ${y}`);
for (let {x, y, value} of matrix) {
  console.log(x, y, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I forgot in ES6+ an equal sign after a parameter is a default value if the parameter is missing or undefined.  The way he did this is just a little awkward.